# Claims and SAML2 confusion

Tags: claims-based-identity, saml-2.0, claims, sts-securitytokenservice, ws-trust

My understanding is that claims are an STS thing based on WS-trust standard and nothing to do with SAML2 standard. WS-trust STS token can use SAML to send claims in that format. Am I correct?

Comment: I have a question: can we add claims to saml metadata?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864159/how-add-claims-to-saml-idp-metadata

Answer (score 8):

Claims is a general concept - a claim is a piece of information about a user.

In SAML2 the same concept is present, but it is named *attribute* instead. There is also a special treatment in SAML2 of the SubjectNameId field - usually the username. When translated to a .NET ClaimsIdentity it is simply just another claim.

Answer (score 4):

Claims are essentially a Microsoft concept. In that world, claims are the signed statements made about an identity by ADFS and interpreted by WIF e.g. Mobile = 12345678.

The mechanism used to pass this information is a SAML token (not to be confused with the SAML protocol).

This contains SAML assertions as above - WIF takes this base information and returns a claims object to the application.

Claims are not restricted to WS-Trust - that's essentially active (web services). They are also used by WS-Federation which is passive (browser).

Answer (score 1):

Claims are a general concept - completely independent of the token type or protocol that is used.